# one hot encode week of month

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

cv is a pandas dataframe storing time series data and I've one hot encoded day of week, month of year.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

days=["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"]
for i in range(5):
    cv[days[i]] = (cv.index.dayofweek == i).astype(int)

months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
for i in range(12):
    cv[months[i]] = (cv.index.month == i+1).astype(int)
```

But when I try to do week of month, it doesn't work.

```
weeks = ['1st Week','2nd Week','3rd Week','4th Week']
for i in range(4):
    cv[weeks[i]] = (cv.index.weekofmonth == i+1).astype(int)

AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'weekofmonth'
```

This is what CV looks like:
[image: how CV is structured]

My desired output would be columns labelled '1st Week','2nd Week','3rd Week','4th Week', with a 1 or 0 corresponding week.

Comment: Can you post an example of  `cv` ?

Comment: @Psidom, I added a picture, does it work?

Comment: Prefer to not  add picture but text for easy copying and pasting. Also is this the desired output ? Would  be helpful to also add the original input.

Comment: By the way, an easy way to copy-paste a dataframe is to run `df.head(6).to_dict()` and copy it into the question.

Comment: @NickODell I tried that, but the table appeared unformatted in the question

Comment: That's true, but it still allows others to copy-paste the dataframe into their Python interpreter. That makes it easier for them to come up with a solution.

Comment: @Psidom desired output added to question

Comment: @TomwardMatthias Please add your imports and show the declaration/type of `cv`.

Comment: @ConfusedLearner added both

Comment: *"...  it doesnt work"*  What happens?  Do you get an error? If so, include the complete error message (i.e. the complete traceback) in the question.  Or is the DataFrame modified in a way that you didn't expect? If so, show what you got, and what you expected.

Comment: The problem is clear then: the [`DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) doesn't have the attribute `weekofmonth`.

Comment: Not really, Im still not able to get week of month

Comment: @ConfusedLearner, you can have a datetimeindex column in a dataframe

Comment: @ConfusedLearner: According to the error, it's `cv.index` (rather than `cv`) that is a `DatetimeIndex`.

Comment: @ConfusedLearner Attributes of that class are here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html?highlight=datetimeindex#pandas.DatetimeIndex.  `dayofweek` is there, but unfortunately the week of month is not available.

Comment: @TomwardMatthias Please post a short snippet of code which generates the object named `cv`. I have no idea what `cv` is. Until I know what `cv` is, I cannot tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon ive added what cv is. it is a dataframe storing time series data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting says that a `pd.DatetimeIndex` doesn't provide the a `weekofmonth` method or attribute. You need to calculate it yourself.

If the 1st of the month falls on a Monday, then the week number is just:

```
week_of_month = (day - 1) // 7 + 1
```

the `(day - 1)` converts the day to 0-based days. The `//7` determines a week number in the range 0-5, and the `+ 1` converts the week number back to a range of 1-6.

If the 1st of the month falls on a different day of the week, then we need to shift by the weekday number, like so:

```
week_of_month = (day + first.weekday() - 1) // 7 + 1
```

The weekday number for Monday is 0, so the formula works for Monday too.

This function calculates the week_of_month:

```
def week_of_month(timestamp):
    """Return the week of the month for a pandas Timestamp."""

    first = timestamp.replace(day=1)
    return (timestamp.day - 1 + first.weekday())//7 + 1
```

It can be applied to your Dataframe to get a week of the month (wom) column which can be used for 1-hot encoding:

```
N = 40
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':np.random.randn(N)}, 
                  index=pd.date_range("2024-12-28", periods=N)
                 )

df['wom'] = df.index.to_series().apply(week_of_month)
for i in range(1,7):
    df[f'week_{i}'] = (df['wom'] == i).astype(int)
```

Old answer (left because the first 3 comments refer to it):

Isn't the week of the month just `(cv.index.day // 7)`?

So something like:

```
for w in range(5)
    cv[f"Week_{i+1}"] = (cv.index.day//7 == i).astype(int)
```

Comment: ive tried something like this but it doesnt seem to work when the dataset spans multiple years like mine does.

Comment: @TomwardMatthias I added an example spanning a new year. It seems to work fine.

Comment: In the example you gave, the Jan 1st and 2nd are in the first week of january, but when looking at a calendar, 4th is in the 2nd week.